# How to have Wordpress send a user confirmation/validation email on signup

Tags: plugins, user-registration

I have a WP 3.3 installed and running great.  My client would like to confirm a valid email address by sending the user a confirmation email containing a link to "confirm".  I have played around with Pie Register a little bit but cannot get it to send emails like it says it can.

Are there other plugins or tools out there capable of the same thing? I don't think its a huge deal but the client won't budge on it.

Also the site sends other emails just fine.

ideas?

Comment: Try http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-members/ since **Register Plus Redux** is now discontinued.

Comment: I dont think that plugin does email validation emails to the registrant

Comment: Doesn't WordPress do this by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plugin does exactly what you need - [Pie Register](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pie-register/)

From Wordpress.org Plugin Directory:

> Email Validation Hate fake emails? Make sure your users are not
>   registering with invalid email accounts by forcing them to click a
>   validation link that's sent out with their registration email. This
>   sets there username to a random generated string (something like:
>   'unverified__h439herld3') so they can't login until they hit that
>   validation link which will put their real username back in place
>   allowing them to login as per usual. Unverified registrations have a
>   defined grace period that will automatically delete an unverified
>   account after a specified period of time, so you don't get clogged up
>   with those fakies. (Manage under Users > Unverified Users)

Comment: not exist anymore

Answer (score 4):

maybe you server hasn't a mail server ,you can use a plugin like WP-Mail-SMTP send email. but i find the pie register plugin register program is not safe,it can register same name and email if the previous register is not active.

Comment: that is worrying

Answer (score -1):

you can use the below when submitting the post of your registration form

```
$userdata = array(
    'user_pass' => $user_pass,
    'user_login' => esc_attr( $_POST['user_name'] ),
    'first_name' => esc_attr( $_POST['first_name'] ),
    'last_name' => esc_attr( $_POST['last_name'] ),
    'nickname' => esc_attr( $_POST['nickname'] ),
    'user_email' => esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ),
    'user_url' => esc_attr( $_POST['website'] ),
    'user_account_type' => esc_attr( $_POST['user_account_type'] ),
    'role' => get_option( 'default_role' ),
);


    $new_user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
    wp_new_user_notification($new_user, $user_pass);
```

which will send confirmation mail to the user